# Stop a setInterval inside its callback

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

Does anyone have any idea how to stop an interval that is situated inside of a function once it's done doing its thing?

Here is what I mean:

```
function renderMessage(message) {

  const renderInterval = setInterval(() => {
    characterIndex++;

    dealerMessage.innerHTML = `
    ${messages[message].slice(0, characterIndex)}
    `;

    if (characterIndex === messages[message].length) {
      clearInterval(renderInterval)
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to render out a message using this function. It does its job fine, but if I don't stop it, subsequent messages keep overriding themselves...

I've tested the if check and it is actually functioning inside the function, yet for some reason the `clearInterval` doesn't work.

Is there any way I can fix this, or do you recommend me to start from scratch?
Note: this method would be very handy for me, so, if possible, I would like to keep it.

Comment: my guess it is more related to calling `renderMessage` more than once and `characterIndex` being used in multiple places.

Comment: clearInterval should work, see the [sandbox](https://jsbin.com/mevimosuyi/1/edit?js,console). so the problem is somewhere in your logic, try to debug

Comment: The browser has a debugger that makes finding these problems even easier than asking a question on Stack Overflow.  See: [Debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/)

Comment: `characterIndex` value is `undefined`

Comment: @MisterJojo you do not know that. Impossible to tell with the code provided. OP need to provide more code in order to see the problem.

Comment: @epascarello  Exactly !  As it is, it is `undefined`

Comment: thank you guys for all the answers :) much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think your 'if' statement of clearInterval should be

```
if (characterIndex===message[message.length]){}
```

Also, I cannot see any initialization of the characterIndex variable. Please do inform if this worked or not.

Comment: Big assumption without all the details.